# Issue in displaying Folium Map inside a function call using Python

Tags: python, folium

I am using the following code to display folium map:

```
import folium

map_hooray = folium.Map(location=[51.5074, 0.1278], zoom_start = 11) 
map_hooray
```

Using the above code the map gets displayed perfectly.

But when I am trying to display the map inside a function call, the map is not getting displayed:

```
import folium

def map_call(a, b):
    print(a,b) ## prints 51.5074 0.1278
    
    map_hooray = folium.Map(location=[a, b], zoom_start = 11) 
    map_hooray # Calls the map to display but map is not getting displayed

map_call(51.5074, 0.1278)
```

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `return` statement

```
def map_call(a, b):
    print(a,b) ## prints 51.5074 0.1278  
   map_hooray = folium.Map(location=[a, b], zoom_start = 11) 
   return map_hooray 

map_call(51.5074, 0.1278)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about it, is to simply use the display function. By this way, you can continue writing further script in the same cell.

Use `display(map_hooray)` within the function.